# Is there a Chromeless Google Chrome that supports Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, chromium, berkelium

I'm looking for a UI totally rendered using HTML / CSS / JS - with no native coding required to modify the browser's Chrome, and preferably other backend API's being available via Javascript.

This is what Mozilla's Chromeless project and Webian offer.

Is there something similar for Google Chrome or Chromium that support's Google's Extensions?

If so, it could allow:

- more browser development, more innovative design
- prototyping new desktop interfaces, instead of relying on existing launchers and docks
- automatically loading tabs out of memory that don't need to be there

I found Berkelium but it's [not clear](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/berkelium/extension/berkelium/9UA7yazBL_4/NrV8TQi2k3EJ) if it supports extensions, or if there is a UI implemented in web standards for it, so that may be a dead end.

Comment: They don't call it "Chrome" for nothing XD

Comment: Fortunately names don't prevent technological progress.

Comment: check out the chrome app store. After you installed the app, you can create a shortcut, or pin it to the taskbar. Once you open the app from one of these shortcut the chrome window doesn't have a addressbar or tabs bar. Example of this is the angry birds app.

Comment: Gerben, that's an example in Chrome itself of Chrome using web standards based UI, but not for the whole browser chrome / shell including tabs, location bar, browser buttons, download toolbars etc.

Comment: https://github.com/paulrouget/firefox.html and http://breach.ccare close recent new options

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/browser.html is another - on the Gecko side, not sure about extensions but it's obviously quite easy to extend.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome's new packaged apps allows you to run your apps without any window chrome:
http://blog.chromium.org/2012/08/the-evolution-of-chrome-packaged-apps.html

In principle, you can build your own UI and drive it through JS.. you have history API, you can navigate the user to different pages, etc. All the pieces are there!

Comment: Does it allow repositioning Chrome extension toolbar buttons, say?

Comment: There is *no* UI whatsoever. So, technically.. no. :)